# error al subir una imagen desde un formulario codeigniter

Tags: php

Hola quiero subir una imagen desde un formulario en *codeigniter* pero tengo 2 problemas:

1: no se como poner la extensión del archivo original.

2: me da este error: **The upload path does not appear to be valid**.

```
$nombreArchivo = "nombre_archivo";

$config['upload_path'] = base_url('/public/imagenes');
        $config['file_name'] = $nombreArchivo . "extension del archivo original";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|jpeg|png";
        $config['max_size'] = "50000";
        $config['max_width'] = "2000";
        $config['max_height'] = "2000";

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('imagen')) {
            //*** ocurrio un error
            $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            die('error');
        }else {

            $nombreImagen = $data['file_name']; 

            $consulta=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `productos`(`nombre`, `imagen`) VALUES ('$nombre','$nombreImagen')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encontrar la extensión utiliza:

```
$nombre = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"]; 
$extension = end((explode(".", $nombre)));
```

Ten en cuenta que tu *input* del archivo debe llevar como atributo `name="imagen"`

`<input type="file" name="imagen"/>`

---

El `$config['upload_path']` no puede ser una url, como haces en tu caso.

Tiene que ser una ruta:

`$config['upload_path'] = './imagenes/'`

Esto te apuntaría a una carpeta *imagenes* que se encuentra en el mismo nivel que el index.php, es decir, te quedaría algo así en el servidor:

- application
- system
- imagenes

  - Tus subidas
- index.php

Comment: Gracias! como podría eliminarla?

Comment: @Doe Eliminar la imagen entiendo??

Comment: si, no se como eliminarla cuando da error el insert.

Comment: no entiendo como se puede borrar una imagen del directorio con unset()

Comment: Mi fallo!! Era `unlink()`!!  Una vez hagas el upload, capturas los datos a una variable con: `$uploaddata = $this->upload->data()`. Después, tomas el valor del path y se lo pasas a `unlink()` : `unlink($uploaddata['full_path']);`

Comment: ok, pero sigue sin funcionar porque hace el insert `$consulta=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO productos(nombre, imagen) VALUES ('$nombre','$nombreImagen')");`  y da error, por lo tanto no puede seguir la ejecución para borrar la imagen. con `unlink($uploaddata['full_path']);`

Comment: Por qué motivo te falla el INSERT? Quizás sería mejor hacer el INSERT a prueba de fallos, no crees?